# Wordpress SSH Upgrade Problem

Tags: ssh, centos, wordpress

[image: Wordpress Error]

I keep getting the same error, any ideas?

1. I have generated a key without a password using `ssh-keygen`
2. I set permissions on the keys to 600
3. I have successfully logged in using `ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa 1**.**.*8.128`
4. I have tried changing hostname to `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`

The server is running CentOS 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because your web server is not running as root and therefore doesn't have access to file's in `/root/`. Run `ps` on the host and grep for the server process name to see the username. It may well be something like `nobody`. If that's the case, I would suggest generating a key specifically for use by the web server and then `chown`ing it to the user the server runs as. Hopefully this will solve your problem :)

Comment: The web server is running as `apache`, changing the `chown` ing the keys to this didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full solution, thanks to [michaelmior](https://serverfault.com/users/14033/michaelmior) for his help, it got me half way.

1. Run this command to generate keys: `ssh-keygen`

   You'll get this output:

   ```
   Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa):
   Created directory ‘/home/user1/.ssh’.
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): (just hit enter, no need for a password)
   Enter same passphrase again: (same thing, hit enter again)
   Your identification has been saved in /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.
   Your public key has been saved in /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
   The key fingerprint is:
   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx user1@server1.example.com
   ```
2. Add the public key to your `authorized_keys` file
3. Move the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to `/usr/local`
4. `chown` the files to the same user as your webserver (in my case apache)
5. `chmod` the files to 600: `chmod 600 id_rsa*`

This should now work.

However, my installation kept hanging, a quick look at the httpd error_log file show me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2966269 bytes) in /var/www/sites/....
```

Adding this code to the Wordpress `wp-config.php` file to temporally increase the amount of memory available:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```