# Wordpress SFTP auto update issues

Tags: php, wordpress, sftp

I have run into an issue with WordPress and ssh.  Essentially,I am trying to enable auto updating with Wordpress over SFTP.  I have followed the directions on [This thead on DigitalOcean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu) up I have a user called `wpftp`.

SSHd into the server as a sudoer, I then login to the server as that user using `login wpftp` and entered the password.  I then ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` and `exit`.

Back as the sudo user, I ran `chown -R wpftp:www-data .ssh/`
than `chmod 0640 .ssh/*`
than `chmod 0700 .ssh`

`ls -lah` gives me the following for `.ssh` folder

```
drwx------ 2 wpftp www-data 4.0K Jan 14 09:00 .ssh
```

looks good so far …

```
cd .ssh/
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
chown wpftp:www-data *
```

gives me the following

```
-rw-r----- 1 wpftp www-data  747 Jan 14 09:04 authorized_keys
-rw-r----- 1 wpftp www-data 3.2K Jan 14 09:00 id_rsa
-rw-r----- 1 wpftp www-data  747 Jan 14 09:00 id_rsa.pub
```

Added `from="127.0.0.1"` to the `authorized_keys` at beginning

Popped the following into wp-config.php

```
define('FTP_PUBKEY','/home/wpftp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY','/home/wpftp/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER','wpftp');
define('FTP_PASS','');
define('FTP_HOST','127.0.0.1:22');
```

I also had an alternate config that I tried, also did not work

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ssh2');
define('FTP_BASE', '/usr/share/nginx/wordpress');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/share/nginx/wordpress/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/usr/share/nginx/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/');
define('FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/wpftp/.ssh/id_rsa.pub');
define('FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/wpftp/.ssh/id_rsa');
define('FTP_USER', 'wpftp');
define('FTP_PASS', '');
define('FTP_HOST', '127.0.0.1:22');
define('FTP_SSL', true);
```

I am getting the following error on the wordpress admin panel:

```
Public and Private keys incorrect for wpftp
```

I look at `/var/log/auth.log` and it says

```
Jan 14 09:09:17 localhost sshd[18313]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]
Jan 14 09:09:20 localhost sshd[18315]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]
Jan 14 09:09:48 localhost sshd[18318]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1: 11: PECL/ssh2 (http://pecl.php.net/packages/ssh2) [preauth]
```

I then went through the common issues on the [article mentioned above](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu)

**1 . Improper permissions on the public key, private key, and the directories that contain them.**

```
/home/wpftp/.ssh/# ls -lah | grep .ssh
drwx------ 2 wpftp www-data 4.0K Jan 14 09:04 .ssh

/home/wpftp/.ssh/# cd .ssh
/home/wpftp/.ssh/# ls -lah
-rw-r----- 1 wpftp www-data  764 Jan 14 09:06 authorized_keys
-rw-r----- 1 wpftp www-data 3.2K Jan 14 09:00 id_rsa
-rw-r----- 1 wpftp www-data  747 Jan 14 09:00 id_rsa.pub
```

I also checked the nginx user

```
# ps aux | grep nginx
root     nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  nginx: worker process
www-data nginx: worker process

#ps aux | grep php
root     18274  0.0  0.1 253360  5476 ?        Ss   09:07   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)      
www-data php-fpm: pool www                                         
www-data php-fpm: pool www                                         
www-data php-fpm: pool www  
(several more pools follow)
```

I also checked the `php5-fpm` and `nginx` error logs, nothing pops up there

**Improper file formatting. If your public or private key has formatting issues, WordPress will reject the key and refuse to use it. The same goes for the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.**
I Checked the id_dsa.pub and it was fine, I am able to `ssh wpftp@localhost` and get in no problem …

This problem has been quite frustrating as the errors are non-descriptive.  I've checked several threads and tried applying the fixes but to no avail.  I have installed the ssh2 library with apt-get install … Any thoughts?

Other References I checked:

[Wordpress SSH Upgrade Problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/182508/wordpress-ssh-upgrade-problem)

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/private-key-incorrect-for-user-error

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/private-key-incorrect-for-wordpress

http://chocotech.blogspot.com/2013/02/update-wordpress-by-using-ssh2-sftp.html

Comment: You'd probably have more success with http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/ . Unlike the built-in SFTP update method this one doesn't require the key live on the file system and all the problems that come with that.

Comment: Thinking you're probably right, will have to re-enable password authentication to get this up and running, thanks

Comment: Running into the exact same issue. Removing from="127.0.0.1" from the authorized keys resolves it, however clearly would like that left in since it will increase security. Will let you know if I discover more.

Answer (score -2):

Why use SFTP?

**Give WordPress to write permission then it will be solved.**

u said you're using Nginx then set

```
chown -r nginx:nginx /var/www/html
```

replace **/var/www/html** with your **site dir** path so WordPress will able to update automatically.